# if and else not working, always showing the same window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I have a problem with my html webpage, I am trying to use a code to show determinate window's login, the problem is no matter what statement(if-else, if-if, or other) I use...always display the same window (mean always display the window I coded on deslogeado.php, I can't make display the window coded on logeado.php).

**Some details:** msg is an string which can bring the word 'cero'(here will display a window to user can login) or other word (here will display a window where user is already logged).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    var flag = 'cero';
    var msg = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "getSesion.php", async: false}).responseText;
    console.log(msg);
    if(msg === flag)
    $('#apDiv7').load('deslogeado.php');
    if(msg !== flag)
    $('#apDiv7').load('logeado.php'); 
        
}
);
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    var flag = 'cero';
    var msg = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "getSesion.php", async: false}).responseText;
    tipo=typeof msg;
    console.log(msg,flag);
    if(msg == flag)
    {
    $('#apDiv7').load('deslogeado.php');
    }else{
    $('#apDiv7').load('logeado.php'); 
    }
}
);
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{ 

$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "getSesion.php", 
    success: function(data) 
    {
        var flag='cero';
        console.log(data,flag);
    
        if(data === flag)
        {
            $('#apDiv7').load('deslogeado.php');
        }else{
            $('#apDiv7').load('logeado.php'); 
        }
    }
})

}
);
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{ 

$.ajax({ url: "getSesion.php", dataType: "json" }).done(function(data) 
{
 if(data.message == flag) 
 {
   $('#apDiv7').load('deslogeado.php');
 }else{
  $('#apDiv7').load('logeado.php'); 
 }

});


});
</script>
```

Tried with 1,2 and 3 equal on if, I don't know if an html attribute problem or what. I really hope someone can help me! My regards!

Comment: "(...)always display the same window" -- what does it display?  Which window?  What do the `console.log` messages give you?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, already tried else if and more detail were added on topic

Comment: You still have not shown us what `getSesion.php` provides.  You are using `console.log` to dump the response, so please share this information with us.

Answer (score 0):

When sending data via ajax in the future, consider formatting it with JSON, which will alleviate the ambiguity of free text (with possible spaces before/after).

You are using AJAX which is asynchronous. You should use the "success" callback, or the done() method of the Deferred Ajax call.

```
$.ajax({ url: "getSesion.php", dataType: "json" }).done(function(data) {
 if(data.message == flag) {
   $('#apDiv7').load('deslogeado.php');
 }else{
  $('#apDiv7').load('logeado.php'); 
 }
});
```

Your php script should return a json formatted object like:

```
{ "message":"cero" }
```

Comment: Thank you Mr waltzZiss but is not working, i think is a problem with is an inside conflict of my pc maybe.